# mail() can't send attachment title with utf-8. English titled attachment passes with utf-8 content

Tags: php

When I send file with eg. title: zażółć gęślą jaźń.pdf it don't pass(I dont get any email) but when i send eg. toSend.pdf all works. **Both attachment contain "zażółć gęślą jaźń"** and email body have no problem with utf-8

I'm trying to pass file by POST( ) and process it in php to make email attachment form it.

```
            $toEmail = 'myEmail@myDomain';
            $from = 'email@realDomain';
            $fromName = 'Formularz kariera';

            // Subject
            $emailSubject = 'CV dla '.$wybor;

            // Message 
            $htmlContent = '<h3> importantcontent zażółć gęślą jaźń</h3>';

            $headers = "From: ".$fromName." <".$from.">";

            if(!empty($uploadedFile) && file_exists($uploadedFile)){

                // Boundary 
                $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

                // Headers for attachment 
                $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

                // Multipart boundary 
                $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 

                // Preparing attachment

                if(is_file($uploadedFile)){

                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                    $fp =    @fopen($uploadedFile,"rb");
                    $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($uploadedFile));
                    @fclose($fp);
                    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"\n" . 
                    "Content-Description: ".basename($uploadedFile)."\n" .
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"; size=".filesize($uploadedFile).";\n" . 
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                }

                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";

                $mail = mail($toEmail, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($emailSubject).'?=', $message, $headers, /*$returnpath,*/ "-f email@realDomain");
                // Delete attachment file from the server
                @unlink($uploadedFile);
```

I dug through the internet in search of a solution but I have found none. I hope that's becouse Im noob in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is good(enought) and problem was POSTFIX's SMTPUTF8 enabled on server ... 
to fix i just.

`postconf "smtputf8_enable = no"`

AVE server logs!